# Jenkins Plugin for AWS CodeDeploy not deploying all files in workspace

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I have a freestyle project (mostly JavaScript and HTML/CSS files) in Jenkins that uses Windows PowerShell to build it specifically using npm commands. It creates a build folder and builds the project as expected with all files. Now in my Workspace on Jenkins that is pulling from a Bitbucket repo I have a number folders and files. In my other projects where I use my Jenkins Plugin for AWS CodeDeploy post build action all my files in my Workspace were deployed. For some reason when this project is deployed to my EC2 instance only my first four folders in the Workspace are being deployed and my two important folders that I need other than my build folder, src and service, are not. I have tried messing with the "Include Files" parameter in the plugin setup but nothing has been successful. Below is a screenshot of the plugin setup:

[image: AWS Plugin Setup]

Please any help is appreciated as this has been an issue for days now, thank you.